# Can one deposit luggage in a safe place in Ibiza?

Tags: luggage, spain

Two of my friends will travel to Ibiza ahead of the booking date and they want to leave their luggage (2 backpacks) somewhere safe. We already spoke with the host, but they have a strict policy about luggage and don't allow to storage before arrival.

Is there another service for that? Does someone knows a better solution than going with their backpacks in a club or a bar overnight?

Comment: A Google search for `left luggage ibiza` turns up at least three options.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I found just one viable option http://www.consignaibiza.com/en/, but there is one problem with this, because you have to do the drop off at 9 am and then pick them up either at 10pm same day or next day. So if you arrive later as 9am you have no good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google search for *luggage storage* returns a number of options which advertise 24/7 availabity:

- [Easy Luggage](https://easyluggage.eu/)
- [Drop & Enjoy](http://dropandenjoy.com/)
- [BagBnB](https://bagbnb.com/luggage-storage/ibiza)
- [Ibiza Bag Drop](https://www.ibizabagdrop.com/)
- [Trunkit Guru](https://www.trunkit.guru/blank)
- [Addicted to Ibiza](http://www.addictedtoibiza.com/vip_extras/luggage-storage/)

Comment: in the end we used this one:  https://consignaibiza.com/en and we were pretty happy with their services.